# Replace service response value with user friendly value using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is need to display a user friendly value in the table which used ng-repeat. Suppose below is the response model from service.

```
[{
   Name : "Hon", 
   Gender : "M"
},
{
   Name : "Hon", 
  Gender : "F"
},
{
   Name : "Hon", 
 Gender : "M"
},
{
   Name : "Jon", 
  Gender : "M"
},
{
   Name : "on", 
  Gender : "F"
}]
```

Currently table is displaying as below

**Name Gender**

Hon         M

Hon      F

Hon   M

Jon     M

on   F

But i want the table to be like

**Name Gender**

Hon         Male

Hon      Female

Hon   Male

Jon     Male

on   Female

I dont want to use any for loop to do this thing. This is the simple example im showing here. But in my case there 3 to 4 column that needs this kind of mapping , there is a chance of getting 1000 records per page.

Can we do this using directives or filters using angular js? if so how? or do you have any better suggestion to this?

Comment: Or you can change the data in transformResponse.

Answer (score 1):

Angular `$filter` is also based on a loop logic.

In fact if you would use an angular filter, the way to go will be this:

```
 .filter('genderTransform', function() {
  return function(input) {

    return input.map((val) => {
      if (val.Gender == 'F') {
        val.Gender = 'Female';
      } else if (val.Gender == 'M') {
        val.Gender = 'Male';
      }
      return val
    })
  }
})
```

Then in template:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data | genderTransform">
   <!-- whatever -->
</div>
```

And here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oopx6b1v/)